# RStudio Server and the confusion of R versions

Tags: r, rstudio-server

So I have installed RStudio Server on a (unix distro) Gentoo Machine. It seems to work fine and I can access the web page from a remote machine.
The problem is that there are two versions of R on the machine a 3.0.1 and a 3.2.3.

The Rstudio Server uses by default the former version that is 3.0.1 located in /usr/bin/R.
While I wish to use the 3.2.3 version located in /usr/local/bin/R. Following [this article on RStudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552316-Configuring-the-Server) I have set these variables within the server config file:

```
rsession-ld-library-path=/usr/local/lib/R
rsession-which-r=/usr/local/bin/R
```

So back on the console of web interface I executed this command:

```
> R.version.string
[1] "R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)"
```

However, when I executed

```
> install.packages("devtools")
Installing package into ‘/home/xxxxx/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘xml2’, ‘evaluate’, ‘roxygen2’, ‘rversions’, ‘git2r’

--2015-12-24 18:45:03--  https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/xml2_0.1.2.tar.gz
Resolving cran.rstudio.com... 54.192.24.253
Connecting to cran.rstudio.com|54.192.24.253|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 74808 (73K) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/Rtmp8EhLy0/downloaded_packages/xml2_0.1.2.tar.gz’

     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 68%  104K 0s
    50K .......... .......... ...                             100% 2.96M=0.5s
(download)
(download)
(etc.)
ERROR: this R is version 3.0.1, package 'xml2' requires R >= 3.1.0
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘xml2’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: this R is version 3.0.1, package 'evaluate' requires R >= 3.0.2
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘evaluate’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: this R is version 3.0.1, package 'roxygen2' requires R >= 3.0.2
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘roxygen2’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: this R is version 3.0.1, package 'git2r' requires R >= 3.0.2
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘git2r’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘xml2’ is not available for package ‘rversions’
* removing ‘/home/haitam/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/rversions’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rversions’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: this R is version 3.0.1, package 'devtools' requires R >= 3.0.2
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp8EhLy0/downloaded_packages’
```

It seems that, at the installation, the R version is the default one, that is 3.0.1. Then I opened Tools/shell and tried:

```
bash-4.2$ R --version
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) -- "Good Sport"
Copyright (C) 2013 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
For more information about these matters see
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
```

So. How can I overcome this confusion of R version. Did I miss something. Is there a config file or an ENV variable that I have to set  ? Should it be during the rstudio installation (cmake) ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You may need to set the default `R` used by BASH. You can make a link to `/usr/local/bin/R` in `~/bin`. And then set the `PATH` ENV in `~/.bash_profile` as `PATH=~/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Do you mean to change the default R ? Wouldn't be any other way around, I want to avoid that.